# ¿Eliminar Varios Registros de una tabla mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ahorita estoy aprendiendo MySQL y tengo una pregunta con respecto a la utilizacion del condicional "WHERE"

Veamos con el ejemplo que estoy haciendo.

Ya teniendo la tabla de pacientes con los campos mencionados en el condigo, hago la inserción de pacientes.

```
insert into pacientes (PacIdentificacion, PacNombres, PacApellidos, PacFechaNacimiento, PacSexo) 
               values (77191957,'Carlos Jose','Arias Rojas','1980-04-12','M'),
                      (1098765678,'Carolina','Rojas Zabala','1984-06-28','F'),
                      (63502720,'Maria Carolina','Rojas Perez','1980-04-12','F'),
                      (63502730,'Maria Alejandra','Torres Cañas','1972-07-15','F'),
                      (37821200,'Evelin','Arias Mendoza','1970-03-25','F'),
                      (37821203,'Maria Fernanda','Rodriguez Perez','1970-07-28','F');
```

Basado en esto se supone que para eliminar un registro deberia hacer lo siguiente

```
delete from pacientes where PacIdentificacion=1140866159 limit 1;
```

Lo cual eliminaria un solo registro con esa identificacion.

Pero y si quiero eliminar más de un registro y utilizando el mismo campo pero con diferentes valores?

Algo asi como...

```
delete from pacientes where PacIdentificacion=1140866000 **AND 63502720** limit 15;
```

En el que la parte negrita seria un valor extra a eliminar (siendo esta la identificacion de Maria Carolina).

**PREGUNTA**

¿De que manera puedo hacer esto? ¿Debo usar "and", "," o algun otro comando?
He utilizado "and", "," y "and PacIdentificacion=63502720" pero no me ha funcionado.

Lo que eventualmente hice fue hacer dos sentencias diferentes con cada identificacion para poder eliminar los dos registros, pero dudo mucho que esto sea viable de hacer cuando haya una base de datos muy grande y se quiera eliminar varios registros bajo un mismo campo.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo y espero poderme haber hecho entender.

Comment: La pregunta esta muy bien formulada, bien hecho!!! recuerda aceptar las respuestas que solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Debe utilizar el operador `IN` para eliminar por un conjunto o grupo de `valores`;

```
DELETE FROM pacientes WHERE PacIdentificacion IN (1140866000, 63502720)
```

Ojo! ves que en este caso estoy solocando los valores entre parentesis `()` separados por coma sin encerrarlos en comillas simples ya que estoy asumiendo que el campo `PacIdentificacion` es de tipo `int` si este es `varchar` o `text` los valores deben ir encerrados entre comillas simples;

Ejemplo

```sql
DELETE FROM pacientes WHERE campoVarchar IN ('some', 'any')
```

Comment: la respuesta es correcta. Me gustaria añadir a la explicación que diste, que se puede hacer como dice el usuario (where campo = 1 or campo = 2 or campo = 3), ya que la base de datos traduce el in como eso. Y que no le funciono, porque hacer campo =1 and campo = 2 es pedirle que un solo registro cumpla esa condicion, lo cual es imposible. Y que las condiciones en un where siempre son "campo condicion valor". AH y el limit no tiene ningun sentido en ninguna de esas condiciones.

Comment: @gbianchi Disculpa pero he leído varias veces mas la pregunta y no menciona un eliminado por varios campos si no por 1 `PacIdentificacion` y su grupo de valores, o no se si estoy entendiendo mal lo que expresas. Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con lo del `limit`

Comment: puse solo un campo, fue para explicarle porque no funciono su and usando los dos valores. fijate dice que probo hacer **He utilizado "and", "," y "and PacIdentificacion=63502720"** por eso mi aclaracion. Siempre sobre el mismo campo.

Comment: @Albert Hidalgo estas en lo correcto, en esa sección me exprese mal, quise decir un eliminado de varios por varios valores en un mismo campo. Y con respecto al limit, en este caso es innecesario (tambien tiene razon el compañero @gbianchi) ya que al ser PacIdentificacion la clave primaria, no deberian haber mas de un registro que cumpla dichas condiciones (refiriendome 1 registro con el primer valor y 1 registro con el segundo, afectando finalmente 2 registros y su elimininacion).

Comment: @MaxJimenez No hay problema, edita tu pregunta y yo editare mi respuesta. no hay problema.

Comment: @MaxJimenez, acepta esta respuesta y borra tu otra respuesta por favor. Utiliza el tilde bajo los votos de esta pregunta para aceptarla...